# Dynamically change form labels in Django/oTree

Tags: python, django

I have a form label that I want to have variable content.  I expose to my template a variable called `outgroup` which I want to be included in the formfield label.  My current (incorrect) attempt looks like this:

```
 {% formfield sent_amount label="How much do you want to send to a "+{{outgroup}} %}
```

But this obviously doesn't work.  What is the correct way to get a variable into the label method?

Comment: Do you need to be able to set the label from the template or would it be acceptable to do it from the view?

Comment: Would be acceptable from the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why couldn't you do something like this in the view?

```
def study(request, studyID):
    if request.method == 'GET' and request.user.is_authenticated:
        form = ContactForm()
        form.fields['from_email'].label = "{}, what's your email?".format(.get_full_name())
```

Use `form.fields["your_label_id"]` to set it.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think about this

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

When the dynamic content to be inserted in the label is a string, instead of an integer, you only need to add () after referring to the dynamic variable (in the example below, after self.player.type)... Like this:

> > > > FIRST go to pages.py:

```
    class Contribute(Page):
        form_model = 'player'
        form_fields = ['type']

        def vars_for_template(self):
            return dict(
                contribution_label='How many {} do you want to contribute?'.format(self.player.type())
            )
```

> > > > SECOND go to the relevant HTML page, Contribute.html

```
    {% formfield player.contribution label=contribution_label %}
```